# Открыть и сохранить файл

Tags: c#

я чайник в программировании, поэтому задаю вопрос, как лучше это сделать: нужно выбрать файл на компьютере, произвести с ним какие-либо действия (например,зашифровываю его),а потом его сохранить. Единственное, что сделала - это открыла файл через OpenFileDialog (при нажатии кнопки). Прошу не кидайтесь тапками, если задаю простейшие вопросы - я не понимаю)

Comment: А файл текстовый или бинарный?

Comment: @Сергей, изначально предполагает, что нужно работать с файлом любого формата,т.е. да, потом буду работать с бинарным

Comment: Отвечать не буду, наверное, но есть несколько способов работы с файлами. Один из них вам уже указали. Но еще можно и через класс `File`, например, так: `byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(<Путь к файлу>)`. У класса `File` и [другие методы есть](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx). А вообще было бы не плохо почитать о работе с файлами в принципе. Информации - тьма. [Вот](http://kbyte.ru/ru/Programming/Articles.aspx?id=69&mode=art) лишь один из примеров.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим вы получили имя файла для его чтения.

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string filename = openFileDialog.FileName;
}
```

Далее есть варианты. К примеру можно считать содержимое в `MemoryStream` для работы с ним в оперативной памяти:

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filename)))
{
    // Делаем что-то важное
}
```

Затем после нужных преобразований сохранить его:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("Какое_то_имя_файла.расширение", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
    memoryStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
    fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: А можно когда голосуете против, рассказать в чём я не прав?